# Can I install .NET Framework 4 on Windows XP Embedded?

Tags: .net, windows, embedded

I can't test it but I need to know if it real , because I started working on project for it with .NET 4 so I must to be sure I can install it there.

So can I install .NET Framework  4 on Windows XP Embedded ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the wiki entry for [Windows XP Embedded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP_editions#Windows_XP_Embedded):

> Windows XP Embedded, commonly abbreviated "XPe", is a componentized version of the Professional edition of Windows XP.

So I'd say yes, because .NET Framework 4 is compatible with Windows XP Professional.

Answer (score 4):

**.NET 4.0 Framework Template available**

Microsoft has published a Windows XP Embedded template for the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 and .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile.

The template can be used with the Image Configuration Editor. It will add all required packages automatically to ensure that the framework works properly with Windows XP Embedded.

http://www.elbacom.com/blog/2010/11/net-4-0-framework-template-available/

Comment: Sadly your link leads to a page that does not contain much information and which has only a link to to the "Microsoft Windows Embedded Standard 7 Compatible Applications website" which does not exist anymore. "We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found."

Comment: @Elmue: Windows XP is end-of-life.

Comment: Yes I know. And Microsoft removes all files from their website, to avoid that people who still use XP can install Framework 4. I *LOVE* Microsoft!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Is possible because I use it.
On Microsoft site you can find:

- wic_x86_enu.exe (a prerequisite for my kind of image)
- dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe (the library itself)

Comment: I confirm that this worked for me too on a Windows XP embedded 2009. If the WIC (Windows Imaging Component) is missing, the stupid Framework 4.0 installer will tell you "Fatal error during installation. Please tell <ReportDestinationName> about this problem". What kind of idiots are working there at Microsoft!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a KBEntry about installing .NET Framework 3 on Windows XP Embedded, here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417255(WinEmbedded.5).aspx

For .NET Framework 3, the answer is "yes" -- but, because Windows XP Embedded is componentized, you need to make sure the Windows installation that you're trying to use has all of the necessary components, and it's quite a long list.  I would expect the answer for .NET Framework 4 is the same, although it may require additional components.  This does mean that you can't assume that .NET Framework will run on *any* arbitrary Windows XP Embedded installation.

Answer (score 1):

I can double some of the previous posts, that this works. 
I have successfully installed a **.NET 4 Application** on a *Rohde&Schwarz ETL TV Analyzer*. **It even worked with the usual Visual Studio Setup project**, including all prerequisites.

Kinda Cool!