# Action in C# 3.0

Tags: c#

I am coding a C# .NET 3.0 asynchronous call to a [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) service. And I get the following error.

> Error 1  Using the generic type 'System.Action' requires '1' type
>   arguments.

But when doing this in .NET 3.5 no error occurs. Doesn't .NET 3.0 support this or I am doing wrong. I have to use .NET 3.0 because iam writing a application for XPe.

This is how my code looks like.

```
AsyncCallback aSyncCallBack =
delegate(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        service.EndSubscribe(result);

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
        { DGStudent.ItemsSource = test; });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); });
    }
};
```

Comment: Does it work if you take away the `(Action)`? Because the cast could be useless... And for your information, you can use up to .NET 4.0 on XPe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374357/can-i-install-net-framework-4-on-windows-xp-embedded

Comment: Are you sure .net 4.0 is working for XP embedded. Because i have tried to install .net 3.5 on XP embedded and it doesnt support it. But i will research more. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Or did you mean Windows Embedded Standard 2009 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-generic [`System.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) was introduced in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 3.5 and cannot be used from .NET 3.0. The compiler thinks you mean the generic [`System.Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) which does require a type parameter.

Comment: Yes, click the first link and note the side-bar.

Comment: click the links and check "Other Versions"

Answer (score 3):

All the `Action` delegates apart from `Action<T>` were only added in .NET 3.5; they're not available in 3.0. If you have a look at the documentation, the [`Action` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) only has versions for 3.5 and 4.0, whereas the [`Action<T>` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) goes back to 2.0.

You'll have to create your own version of a no-args delegate, or use something similar like `MethodInvoker` in winforms.